# Decrypting WLAN (WPA2) Traffic - What kind of Antenna to use?

Tags: wireless, decryption, sniffing, aircrack-ng

In a Penetration test after receiving the PSK of a WPA2 WLAN it's possible to decrypt the wireless traffic using `airdecap-ng` for example. This works well as long as one recorded the associated four-way-handshake of every connection.  I prefer this method because it's purely passive and as such it's not detectable on a network level.

The downside of this is that as a passive part I can't tell the accesspoint or the client to resend traffic I did not receive or did receive in a corrupted way. This means that I have to assure a good reception quality in the first place. We are talking about one single accesspoint here. *Which kind of Antenna is the most appropriate for ths situation? What are the influence facors I have to pay attention to?*

Comment: Hardware (or software) recommendations are off-topic for InfoSec.SE.

Comment: If you reword your question to something like `What qualities should I look for in an antenna to be used for this purpose.`, the question is likely acceptable for this site.